# PHP - Making cookie in login form

Tags: php

I am trying to keep a person logged in the system till the page is open in the browser. My code is:

```
($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($hostname,  $username,  $password)) or DIE('NOT Connected!');
 ((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE $dbname")) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
 $login = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM student WHERE (name = '" .addslashes($_POST['username']) . "') and ( password = '" .($_POST['password']) . "')");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($login); 
 $a = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE (username = '" .addslashes($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" .sha1($_POST['password']) . "')");
 $r=mysqli_fetch_array($a); 
 if($row){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['lname'] = $row['lname'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $row['pass']
setcookie("cookname", $_SESSION['name'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
setcookie("cookpass", $_SESSION['pass'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
    header ("location: ../../gui-student.php");
    }
    elseif($r){
 $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['id'];

header ("location: gui-admin.php");
    }
    else {
        header ("location: ../../index.html?err");
        }
 if($row==1)
       {
      session_start();
       $_SESSION['username']=$userName;
     header("location: ../../gui-employee.php");
     exit();
     }
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. I am new to cookies and i don't know know how to check the cookies on the gui-student.php page.
Thanking you in Advance
Rgds
Bhawna

Comment: I'm curious... Do you just type random spaces for line indentation? A couple taps here and there on the old spacebar?

Comment: Okay, so you're setting cookies. A good start. Are you checking them?

Comment: Code may or may not be pretty. But it's usually easier to follow and get correct when there's *some* consistency. In particular the doubled mysql query looks odd and perhaps redundantly obfuscates the code structure. -- You'll have to be more concrete on what happens / or what goes wrong. "Not working" isn't a valid problem description.

Comment: @BitwiseCreative How to do that?

Comment: @Bhaamb http://davidwalsh.name/php-cookies

Comment: @BitwiseCreative This is simple but how do i check the cookies in the gui-student.php

Comment: Security note: it seems you're storing a user password in a cookie?  Even if since it's hashed (assumption, since if it's not hashed _and_ you're storing it in a cookie...), this should probably be avoided.

Comment: Why do you want to use cookies for this? I think session is all you need.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php you will find some examples there for setting and using cookies. But for login you should use sessions

Answer (score 0):

To check for cookie, use..

`$_COOKIE['cookie_name'];` in your case it would be `$_COOKIE['cookname'];` or `$_COOKIE['cookpass'];`

This will give the value you have set in cookie, i.e, `$_SESSION['name']` or  `$_SESSION['pass']`.

Comment: And I would suggest you to go for `session` in stead if you want to store user info until the page is closed...